# Python module pyGTiff aligning data

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, python-2.7

I have been working with pyGTiff for a while and it works great. However my gis data does not have the same projection and extent. I saw that in the repository a  a jupyter notebook with a test example aligning data is provided.
Unfortunately the code throws this Error:

> NotImplementedError: You must build the supplementary C++ module to
>   enable this method.

```
from pyGTiff import geotiff
import numpy as np    
LS8 = geotiff('LC80200312014149LGN00/LC80200312014149LGN00_B5_subset.TIF')
NED = geotiff('nedwashtenaw.tif') #Align NED data with LS8 data 
NEDn = LS8.intersect(NED,nodata=[0],resampleType=2)
```

The last line is the source of the error.
The Ipython notebook and example data can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/rsawtell/pygtiff/wiki/Examples)

Environment:
Canopy Python 32bit,
GDAL 2.0.1,
pyGTIFF 1.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is a mistake (`NED = geotiff('nedwashtenaw.tif') Align NED data with LS8 data`)  but

```
from pyGTiff import geotiff
import numpy as np    
LS8 = geotiff('LC80200312014149LGN00/LC80200312014149LGN00_B5_subset.TIF')
NED = geotiff('nedwashtenaw.tif') # Align NED data with LS8 data 
NEDn = LS8.intersect(NED,nodata=[0],resampleType=2)
```

#### New

I compile myself PyGTiff with the flags of GDAL (gdal_config) and

- with GDAL 1.11.x, the script works
- with GDAL 2.x, error

  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "pyGTiff/geotiff.py", line 771, in intersect
    raise NotImplementedError("You must build the supplementary C++ module to enable this method.")
  NotImplementedError: You must build the supplementary C++ module to enable this method.

The last version of pyGTiff dates from 2014 and GDAL 2.x from 2015 and 2016, therefore ....

Comment: thank you gene,  I forgot to outcomment the piece of code in my post but that was not the problem why it didnt work. Could it be an dependency issue with other installed modules? Or the version of installed GDAL on hich pyGTIFF is based? I edited my question and added more information about my environment.

Comment: look above in New

Answer (score 0):

You need to build/install the package with the C++ bindings...

clone package, cd to pyGTiff,

python setup.py build
sudo python setup.py install

you probably did the above with the "--noc" flag attached is my guess... "noc" stands for "NO C" as in "no c++"